# How to define column and row in a LinearLayout dynamically?

Tags: android-layout

I'm trying to create dynamically this XML:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"    >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/topleft"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"         
            >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                      
            android:src="@drawable/tetona"          
              />      

     ></LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/topRigth"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"  
        >        
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                      
            android:src="@drawable/tetona" />                    
     ></LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/bottomRight"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"  
        >        
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                      
            android:src="@drawable/tetona" />                    
     ></LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/BottonLeft"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"  
        >        
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                      
            android:src="@drawable/tetona" />                    
     ></LinearLayout>

</GridLayout>
```

I can create LinearLayouts inside a loop such as:

```
GridLayout gridlay = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridpadre);
gridlay.setColumnCount(2);
gridlay.setRowCount(2);

for (int i=0; i<(gridlay.getRowCount()); ++i){
    for(int j=0; j<gridlay.getColumnCount(); ++j){          

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);   
        layout.setId(id);   
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(160,200)); 
        gridlay.addView(layout);
```

But... how can I set LinearLayout `android:layout_column="i"` and `android:layout_row="j"` dynamically in order to put it in the position i and j relative to the gridlayout? 
Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try doing the following: `layout.setOrientation(VERTICAL);` then try `layout.setHorizontalGravity(j)` since I don't have a computer equipped with any way to test it I'm not sure it will work, but its worth a shot.